# Pattern in string count for C

Tags: c, strings

I am trying to write a function that will count the occurrences of a pattern in a string without overlap. This is what I have right now.

```
size_t count(char *string, char *pat) {
    size_t patternLength = strlen(pat);
    size_t stringLength = strlen(string);
    size_t count = 0;
    char *compareString = malloc(patternLength + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        if (i + patternLength > stringLength) return count;
        strcpy(compareString, &string[i], i+patternLength);
        if (strcmp(compareString, pat) == 0) {
            count++;
            i--;
            i+=patternLength; /* non overlapping find */
        }

    }
    free(compareString);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Drop the Intermediate String**

You're allocating `compareString` and `strcpy`ing into it just so that you can use `strcmp`. But instead, there's also `memcmp`, which lets you compare from the original string directly:

**Fix the loop condition**

You're not really looping from `0` to `stringLength`, you're looping from `0` to `stringLength - patternLength`. Splitting up those concerns in two is confusing.

**Adjusting `i`**

You have:

```
i--;
i+=patternLength; /* non overlapping find */
```

We can do both in one:

```
i += patternLength - 1;
```

**Better solution**:

```
size_t count(char *string, char *pat) {
    size_t patternLength = strlen(pat);
    size_t stringLength = strlen(string);
    size_t count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength - patternLength; i++) {
        if (memcmp(string+i, pat, patternLength) == 0) {
            count++;
            i += patternLength - 1;
        }

    }

    return count;
}
```